# Constructor for a no-named struct

Tags: c++

I have a class something like that:

```
template <class T>
class bag
{
public:

private:
 typedef struct{void* prev; struct{T item; unsigned int count;} body; void* next;}* node; 
 typedef struct{
  node operator->() { return current; }
  operator(){;} // <- i can not do that, right?

 private:
  node current;
 } iterator;
//...
};
```

So, how to write a constructor for the bag::iterator?

Comment: A "no-named" struct is called anonymous.

Comment: @Peter G.: not anonymous, this is an "unnamed class defined in a typedef declaration" `7.1.3/5`

Comment: Thanks Cubbi, I stand corrected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make some nice name for it :-)

```
typedef struct NoName1 {void* prev; NoName1(){}; struct NoName2{T item; unsigned int count; NoName2() {}} body; void* next;}* node;
```

EDIT: LOL sorry, wrote it for the wrong one, but the principle is the same :-)

Answer (score 5):

There is no way to write a constructor for `bag::iterator` because iterator is a typedef name, which are prohibited from being used as constructor names:

`14882:2003 12.1/3`

> a *typedef-name* that names a class shall not be used as the *identifier* in the declarator for a constructor declaration.

There is even an example in the standard, although in a different paragraph, `7.1.3/5`:

```
typedef struct {
    S();         //error: requires a return type because S is
                 // an ordinary member function, not a constructor
} S;
```

You will have to give that struct a name, if you want a user-defined constructor. The `typedef struct { } name;` style of programming is usually discouraged by C++ style guides anyway, in favor of `struct name { };`.